# C# - convert anonymous type to observablecollection

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection, anonymous-types

I have a LINQ statement that returns an anonymous type. I need to get this type to be an ObservableCollection in my Silverlight application. However, the closest I can get it to a

List myObjects;

Can someone tell me how to do this?

```
ObservableCollection<MyTasks> visibleTasks = e.Result;
var filteredResults = from visibleTask in visibleTasks
                      select visibleTask;

filteredResults = filteredResults.Where(p => p.DueDate == DateTime.Today);
visibleTasks = filteredResults.ToList();  // This throws a compile time error
```

How can I go from a anonymous type to an observable collection?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ekin suggests, you can write a generic method that turns any `IEnumerable<T>` into an `ObservableCollection<T>`. This has one significant advantage over creating a new instance of `ObservableCollection` using constructor - the C# compiler is able to infer the generic type parameter automatically when calling a method, so you don't need to write the type of the elements. This allows you to create a collection of anonymous types, which wouldn't be otherwise possible (e.g. when using a constructor).

One improvement over Ekin's version is to write the method as an extension method. Following the usual naming pattern (such as `ToList` or `ToArray`), we can call it `ToObservableCollection`:

```
static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T> 
  (this IEnumerable<T> en) { 
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(en); 
}
```

Now you can create an observable collection containing anonymous types returned from a LINQ query like this:

```
var oc = 
  (from t in visibleTasks   
   where t.IsSomething == true
   select new { Name = t.TaskName, Whatever = t.Foo }
  ).ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using generics? I mean, with inline code and without creating a real type. Something like ObservableCollection<typeof(new {Property A, Property B})> ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the job using type inference features:

```
private static ObservableCollection<T> CreateObservable<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<T>(enumerable);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var oc = CreateObservable(args.Where(s => s.Length == 5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this:

```
visibleTasks = new ObservableCollection<MyTasks>(filteredResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* that your object is an `ObservableCollection` indeed? If yes, you can just cast: `visibleTasks = (ObservableCollection)filteredResults;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var filteredResults = from visibleTask in visibleTasks
                      where(p => p.DueDate == DateTime.Today)
                      select visibleTask).ToList();
```

(filteredResults will contain your desired list)